# Android: How to add alarm if it doesn't exist

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I'd like to have a button that when pressed will automatically add an alarm for a given time, if an alarm for that time doesn't exist. And if it does already exist I'd like it to make sure that that alarm is on. How do I do this. When I did research it looks like I have to do something with `AlarmManager`, but I got confused about how to use it and how I'd get it to do what I want.

The alarm would be a once and done thing as well. In that, if I set the button to automatically create an alarm for 6:30am, it would set an alarm for the next 6:30am. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You would benefit about learning about persistent storage for storing your scheduled alarms. AlarmManager is **NOT** going to track what alarms you set in a way that you can query! Because of this you will need to schedule them appropriately on boot. Once you see how persistent storage works, then you re-utilize that data and schedule it with AlarmManager. Also would recommend you read the docs @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @JoxTraex I still am unsure about how to set an alarm. Note that I don't mean an alarm that runs a bit of code at a certain time, I mean a wake-up alarm, such as the alarm that wakes you up in the morning.